# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button within the `ItemTemplate` of my Listview:

```
<asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" Visible="false" Enabled="false" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
```

Then with my `ItemDataBound` event for my Listview I have:

```
protected void listview_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
   var btn_edit = e.Item.FindControl("EditButton") as Button;

   if(isOwner == false)
   {
     // code here..
   }
   else
   {
     btn_edit.Enabled = true;
     btn_edit.Visible = true;
   }

}
```

The edit button shows when I load the page so it shows that the `btn_edit.Visible = true;` is working, however when I click on it, it breaks and gives me this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I know about about these errors however I don't understand why I am getting this error? Especially when it's reaching the `Visible = true;` statement?

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

PS: The button used to work before I set the Enabled and Visible in the code and in the XML

UPDATE: I have narrowed the error down by debugging on the line, within the ItemDataBound event it shows that the btn_edit is not null and shows the Text and CommandName property values, however when I click on it, it falls through the same event again and this time shows the btn_edit is null. So when I click on it thats when the error is showing

Comment: I suspect `btn_edit` is `null`, so `FindControl` returns nothing. Put a breakpoint right after the `FindControl` line and inspect if it is indeed `null`.

Comment: If the error occurs on the `Button_Click` event, then the error is in the code of that event.

Comment: @JoshPart How though? It was working before the button was set to enabled and visible

Comment: @JoshPart Also I don't have a click event as I am using commandName etc

Comment: @FrankJ I have put a breakpoint and the result is correct, it shows the CommandName and the Text property values

Comment: @FrankJ Okay, I have debugged when it loads and it finds the button and shows the correct values, however when I click on it, it is the opposite. Why is it failing when I click on it? Also to be specific, when I click on it, it is falling into the ItemDataBound since I am using CommandName and not using a click event

Comment: I don't know enough about how ASP.net resolves 'FindControl' requests. If it is similar to WPF and your button is a node outside of the tree structure `e.Item` can search for in, it would simply not find it. Maybe somebody with ASP.net experience can chime in here.

Comment: @mason I have updated my question to prove it is different to the duplicated question

Answer (score 0):

You should always check which item type is being bound to avoid this kind of errors.
For instance ([MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
protected void listview_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
       var btn_edit = e.Item.FindControl("EditButton") as Button;

       if (isOwner == false)
       {
         // code here..
       }
       else
       {
         btn_edit.Enabled = true;
         btn_edit.Visible = true;
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have added this and it still does not work

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are trying to achieve with that button? To have a better idea of the whole picture. For instance, your button have set a commandname; maybe it is changing the active item template of ListView and that's why it is "not existing" anymore after postback; because another template (the edit item template of the list view) is being shown.

Comment: I think what you have just said could be the problem! Do you have any idea how I would solve it, if that was the case?